# "Similar in style" and "similar in their styles"

Tags: phrase-usage

When I compare two shirts' styles, I think I can say:

> Those shirts are similar in style.

Since the shirts' styles are similar, not the same, can I also idiomatically say:

> Those shirts are similar in their styles.

Google apparently suggests it is not popular, but why is it incorrect? And if "similar in their styles" works, I am also wondering if this is applicable to phrases with other terms (meaning, size, etc.)

Comment: "in their styles" is a tad more elevated in register than "in style".

Comment: This is clunky: Those artists are similar in style.

Comment: This has more grace: Those artists are similar in their styles.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, "similar in *their* style" is used idiomatically, but not very often. [This ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=similar%20in%20style%2C%20similar%20in%20their%20style&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimilar%20in%20style%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csimilar%20in%20their%20style%3B%2Cc0) that the phrase "similar in style" is used far more often. Idioms are widely accepted in everyday speech although may not be strictly "correct".

The two *could* be used interchangeably in some situations. However, as "their" is a possessive pronoun, it may not always be appropriate to use it if you are speaking about some*thing* as opposed to some*one*.

Personally, I agree with your example:

> Those shirts are similar in style.

I wouldn't say "their" style because I feel that the inanimate T-shirts do not *possess* a style; rather they *were styled* by a designer.

But as people tend to choose a style of dress for themselves it is common to hear:

> My daughter and her friend *have* a similar style.

As this is possessive, I would suggest it is acceptable then to also say:

> My daughter and her friend are similar in their style (of dress).